# How can we play/buffer only few minutes of a video in Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, buffering

I need to play first 2 mins of a video. Using onBufferingUpdate() i get the percentage that is buffered. But by the time onPrepared is called i get buffered % as 40. Which is more than 2 mins of a video. (Considering i have a video of 30 mins)

Is there any way i can play/buffer video for only 2 mins ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer size is pre-set into the firmware. All you can do is keep tabs on how much the buffer is filled, and even that is just on a percentage basis.
The size is set in `frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/include/NuCachedSource2.h`

check out this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29870) on code.google.com.

**Edit:**
You can get current position of the video by using`mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();` which will return you  the current position in milliseconds and now you will have to use a `AsynTask`

```
private class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mVideoView.start();            
        do {            
            try {
                if(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() == TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(yourMinutes)){
                    mVideoView.stop();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } while (mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() != mVideoView.getDuration());
        return null;
    }
```

You can start the `AsyncTask` by using `new myAsync().execute();` statement.

Comment: If thats the case then is it possible to play for only 2 or say 10  mins, if i ignore the buffer ?