# 3 seconds latency while streaming with Wowza Server

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, latency, wowza

I'm trying to develop a live streaming application with RTSP protocol.

On the PC with the Wowza Server, I execute the following command :

Code:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Name_Of_My_Cam":audio="Name_Of_My_Microphone" -vcodec
h263p -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://<Wowza_server_ip_adress>:1935/live/test
```

And I'm trying to play this stream on a VideoView on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Lite. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    // Receive RTSP video from Wowza Server
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://<Wowza_server_ip_adress>:1935/live/test"));
    vv.requestFocus();
    vv.start();
}
```

I managed to read the video and the sound but it makes 3 secondes (or more...) to start and I keep this delay during all the streaming. It is very annoying because I want to develop a call session.

Does anybody know how to reduce this delay? Is it a Wowza issue?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions on [How to achieve the lowest latency from capture to playback](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?81-How-to-achieve-the-lowest-latency-from-capture-to-playback)

Comment: Yes. I have tried to change the StreamType to "live-lowlatency" and to modify the properties of my application. But it change nothing.

Comment: I tried to lauch the stream with the application "XMTV Player" and it works (I have less than 1 sec of delay). So I guess the issue is in the implementation of the VideoView. Maybe the buffering is to low ??

Comment: Apparently the VideoView buffer size is [hardcoded in the firmware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667689/how-can-we-play-buffer-only-few-minutes-of-a-video-in-android). You might need a custom lib.

Comment: I found this one : [vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle). I will test today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the [vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/vitamio-sample/src/io/vov/vitamio/demo/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java) library.
Instead of a VideoView, I implement the custom MediaPlayer (see the sample "MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java"). The delay is less than 1 sec. So the streaming from my Wowza Server to the android phone work well.

Comment: which version of vitamio did you use? I am currently using ffmpeg to send only my audio stream to wowza. However the audio stream reaches wowza after say 3-4 secs once the ffmpeg is fired from desktop. How did u manage to solve this ?